# How to unrar all RAR files in a folder to a specific target folder?

Tags: batch-file, unrar

I have a file batch to unrar all RAR files in a folder into a subfolder.

```
C:\test\sub-folder\file.rar -> C:\test\sub-folder\fileunrar
```

But when I run it, the file is unpacked to the base folder:

```
C:\test\sub-folder\file.rar -> C:\test\fileunrar
```

This is the batch file I'm currently using:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd C:\test
SET PATH=C:;C:\Program Files\WinRAR;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;%PATH%
FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ('DIR /B') DO unRaR x -y -r -o- *.rar
EXIT
```

Why are the RAR archives extracted to base folder?

Comment: Why are you using a `for /F` loop? why not just executing `unrar` directly? you are not using variable `%%d` anyway...

Comment: The question is vague. And currently the `for` loop meaninglessly executes `unrar` many times over unpacking exactly the same files.

Answer (score 3):

There is the text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR* which is the manual for the console version `Rar.exe` containing also all the commands and switches supported by `UnRAR.exe` which of course can't create, update or repair RAR archives.

Running in a command prompt window just `UnRAR.exe` without any parameter results in getting displayed all supported commands and switches with a brief description.

`UnRAR`, `Rar` and `WinRAR` support all unpacking multiple *.rar files in a directory without the need of a batch file with a **FOR** loop with a single command.

For unpacking a multi-volume archive it is enough to specify on command line the file name of the first RAR archive file. `UnRAR`, `Rar` and `WinRAR` automatically detect that this file is the first file of a multi-volume archive and processes automatically all volumes.

Of course `UnRAR`, `Rar` and `WinRAR` do not process each *.rar file more than once when unpacking all *.rar files of a folder containing multiple separate archives as well as 1 or more multi-volume archives.

For unpacking multiple independent *.rar archives with a single line the switch `-ad` might be useful to avoid that the contents of all independent archives are merged together into same directory.

For unpacking all *.rar archives in directory `C:\Temp` to directory `C:\Temp\Extracted` with merging the files and folders from all archives to this directory and automatically overwrite all existing files use following command:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe" x -c- -cfg- -inul -o+ -y "C:\Temp\*.rar" "C:\Temp\Extracted\"
```

Extracting all *.rar files in `C:\Temp` with getting each independent archive extracted into a subdirectory in `C:\Temp\Extracted` with name of archive file can be achieved with:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe" x -ad -c- -cfg- -inul -o+ -y "C:\Temp\*.rar" "C:\Temp\Extracted\"
```

The switch `-ad` makes the difference in output folder.

It does not matter if `C:\Temp\Extracted` already exists or does not yet exist for unpacking the archives. `UnRAR`, `Rar` and `WinRAR` create on extraction always the entire directory tree to output folder if that is necessary and of course possible (write permissions, drive/share exists and not write protected).

Let us look on an example for making the difference more clear.

There are the 2 RAR archives `MyFirstArchive.rar` and `AnotherArchive.rar` in `C:\Temp` containing following files and folders.

**MyFirstArchive.rar**

```
 Attributes      Size    Date   Time   Name
----------- ---------  -------- -----  ----
    .......      6302  11-10-15 15:25  zzz.doc
    .......    940942  26-08-15 08:07  yyy.txt
    .......   1430688  06-10-14 05:49  Folder1\xxx.pdf
    ...D...         0  12-10-15 07:10  Folder1
----------- ---------  -------- -----  ----
              2377932                  4
```

**AnotherArchive.rar**

```
 Attributes      Size    Date   Time   Name
----------- ---------  -------- -----  ----
    .......     28165  08-01-12 17:50  zzz.doc
    .......      3743  29-10-14 07:18  Folder2\index.txt
    .......     27141  29-10-14 07:18  Folder1\index.txt
    .......    940942  26-08-15 08:07  index.txt
    ...D...         0  12-10-15 07:10  Folder1
    ...D...         0  12-10-15 07:12  Folder2
----------- ---------  -------- -----  ----
               999991                  6
```

The first command results in:

- **C:\Temp\Extracted**

  - **Folder1**

    - index.txt
    - xxx.pdf
  - **Folder2**

    - index.txt
  - index.txt
  - yyy.txt
  - zzz.doc

`zzz.doc` in `AnotherArchive.rar` has overwritten `zzz.doc` in `MyFirstArchive.rar`.

The second command with switch `-ad` results in:

- **C:\Temp\Extracted**

  - **MyFirstArchive**

    - **Folder1**

      - xxx.pdf
    - yyy.txt
    - zzz.doc
  - **AnotherArchive**

    - **Folder1**

      - index.txt
    - **Folder2**

      - index.txt
    - index.txt
    - zzz.doc

The folder and files of the 2 archives are extracted to separate folders with name of archive file.